# What's the correct way to extract a regexp match in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have found two ways to extract matches in Python:

1.

```
def extract_matches(regexp, text):
  matches = re.match(regexp, text)
  if matches:
    return matches.group(1)
```

2.

```
def extract_matches(regexp, text):
  try:
    return re.findall(regexp, text)[0]
  except IndexError:
    return None
```

Which one would you suggest me to use? And do you know any other ways to do this?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: The semantics are different.  The second finds more than the first.  This seems like asking which is better `2+2` or `(2+2,3.1415928)[0]`?  They don't seem to be equivalent in any way except coincidentally.  Can you explain more why you're confused?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would more often use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=finditer#re.search) (which returns *any* match, not just one constrained to start at the beginning of the string as [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=finditer#re.match) does!) if I'm looking for just one match, [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=finditer#re.finditer) if I want to loop over all matches.  Never [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=finditer#re.findall) if I'm going after only one match though, that's wasted effort with no upside!